# Overriding const_missing returns `NameError uninitialized constant` in non-dev environments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, ruby-2.6

I have the following code in my rails app

```
# app/models/test_module/text_class.rb
module TestModule
  class TestClass
  end
end

# app/models/test_module.rb
module TestModule
  def self.const_missing(name)
    super(delete_end_number(name.to_s).to_sym)
  end

  def self.delete_end_number(str)
    str.gsub(/\d+$/,'')
  end
end
```

When it runs in development it works

```
>> TestModule::TestClass1
=> TestModule::TestClass
```

When I run it in production however I get

```
NameError (uninitialized constant TestModule::TestClass)
```

If I just copy `TestModule::TestClass` into the console it works. It seems just to not work with the `const_missing` method.

I suspect it may have something to do with the autoloading as when I set `config.cache_classes` and `config.eager_load` to true in development.rb it happens there too. I can't seem to figure out how to get it to work in cached environments though.

Answer (score 1):

Change from

```
super(delete_end_number(name.to_s).to_sym)
```

To

```
const = delete_end_number(name.to_s).to_sym
ActiveSupport::Dependencies.load_missing_constant(self, const)
```